# GruntJS - zip only specified files into an archive

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

Is Grunt (grunt custom script) capable of packaging only specific files/folder into zip?

That would be useful for example in automating Chrome Extension .zip creation - I want to skip all bower files - except for those files which to be included in the production version (minimized versions only).

Any suggestion or links much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to bundle a Chrome extension, I've used [Grunt CRX](https://github.com/oncletom/grunt-crx) with some success. You can exclude files / use grunt templates in the task. The only caveat is that it is only for *private* extensions at the moment.